# How to dynamically import named exports TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

`const { SchemaLink } = require('apollo-link-schema')`

I've tried `const { SchemaLink } = import('apollo-link-schema')`, but it doesn't work. ESLint still shows an error `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`

How can i dynamically import a named export in TypeScript?

Comment: It would be `const { SchemaLink } = await import('apollo-link-schema')`. Also, linter errors are not the same as compiler errors. If you disagree with the linter, perhaps that rule is not for you.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks. Since it's a promise based `import`, could you show an example with a Promise instead of await/async?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike `require`, JavaScript's dynamic `import` is asynchronous, returning a Promise for the specified module. Therefore, the module and its exports are only available after the Promise has successfully resolved. We can use the standard Promise API directly

```
import('apollo-link-schema').then(({ SchemaLink }) => {
  // Use SchemaLink here
});
```

Additionally, By taking advantage of `async`/`await`, we can write

```
const { SchemaLink } = await import('apollo-link-schema');
// Use SchemaLink here
```

Comment: Just as a note here to document the mistake I was making - if you have a default export, you must do `const SchemaLink = (await  import('apollo-link-schema')).default` or equivalent.

Comment: @GeoffDavids I see. In that case, the most readable syntax is `const {default: SchemaLink} = await  import('apollo-link-schema');`